# Suppress kinks in a plot matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, plot, smoothing

I have a csv file which contains data like below:[1st row is header]

```
Element,State,Time
Water,Solid,1
Water,Solid,2
Water,Solid,3
Water,Solid,4
Water,Solid,5
Water,Solid,2
Water,Solid,3
Water,Solid,4
Water,Solid,5
Water,Solid,6
Water,Solid,7
Water,Solid,8
Water,Solid,7
Water,Solid,6
Water,Solid,5
Water,Solid,4
Water,Solid,3
```

The similar pattern is repeated for State: "Solid" replaced with Liquid and Gas.
And moreover the Element "Water" can be replaced by some other element too.
Time as Integer's are in seconds (to simplify) but can be any real number.
Additionally there might by some comment line starting with # in between the file.

Problem Statement: I want to eliminate the first dip in Time values  and smooth out using some quadratic or cubic or polynomial interpolation [please notice the first  change from 5->2 --->8. I want to replace these numbers to intermediate values giving a gradual/smooth increase from 5--->8].

And I wish this to be done for all the combinations of Elements and States.

Is this possible through some sort of coding in Matlab etc ?

Any Pointers will be helpful !!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I was a expecting some quick function which could crunch the entire file, while retaining the order, it seems I will have to parse the file and seprate each of above block then apply polyfit or interp1 , then write it again :) Anyways pals thanks a lot for help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function for 1D-interpolation. The syntax is

```
yi = interp1(x,y,xi,method)
```

where `x` are your original coordinates, `y` are your original values, `xi` are the coordinates at which you want the values to be interpolated at and `yi` are the interpolated values. `method` can be `'spline'` (cubic spline interpolation), `'pchip'` (piece-wise Hermite), `'cubic'` (cubic polynomial) and others (see the documentation for details).

Answer (score 1):

You have alot of options here, it really depends on the nature of your data, but I would start of with a simple moving average (MA) filter (which replaces each data point with the average of the neighboring data points), and see were that takes me. It's easy to implement, and fine-tuning the MA-span a couple of times on some sample data is usually enough.

http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html

I would not try to fit a polynomial to the entire data set unless I really needed to compress it, (but to do so you can use the `polyfit` function).